# Как перенести изображение на новый холст средствами JS?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Есть изображение с высоким разрешением, допустим 2048×4096 px. Как перенести это изображение(создать из него новое) на новый холст с разрешением 1920×1080px, используя javascript? Аналог такой функции на php imagecopyresampled()

Comment: Для этого можно использовать canvas. Отрисовать в нём изображение в нужном размере и далее сохранить его в base64 или blob. Код ресайза можете [подсмотреть тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19262141/resize-image-with-javascript-canvas-smoothly) для сохранения изображения использовать toBlob [полный пример тут](https://jsfiddle.net/xfzrea2t/)

Comment: А нельзя без фреймворка? Тем более мне не нужны остальные функции(обрезать,дорезать и т.д.), а только скопировать изображение на холст.

Comment: Где вы в приведенных ссылках увидели фреймворк?